# PHP difference in versions, wrong variable gets overwritten

Tags: php

I migrated our website from old host to new host with newest PHP version.
Some problems occurred, I managed to solve them.

Now 1 thing is driving me mad.
Please see the below snippet, maybe somebody could explain me why this happens.

```
    $cms_items = $items;
     $cms_items->settings = $settings_cms; 
     $cms_items->settings->table->head = 1; //head in overview mode.
//var_dump($cms_items);
//var_dump($items);
```

The settings are not just getting overwritten for `$cms_items` but also for $items.
I dont know why.

When I remove `$cms_items->settings = $settings_cms;` and dump $items nothing is overwritten and everything is fine.

So somehow this line `$cms_items->settings = $settings_cms;` not just changes settings for `$cms_items` but also for $items.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: That's because all object variables are referenced to that object. If you want to create copy of `$items`, use `$cms_items = clone $items;`

Comment: @mlask That sounds like an answer :)

Comment: It depends on the value type of a variable... If its an object its used as reference, else its used by value. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: Thanks guys. So this changed in the newer PHP versions ?

Comment: I always used below code if I wanted to copy var1 to var2.
$var2 = $var1.

I dont knew this makes them the same / equal and I need to put clone infront in order to copy it.

Strange.. I was learned to just $var1 = $var2.

Comment: This changed between PHP4 and PHP5

Comment: Any documentation about this change in between the versions ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php However, php5 was released about 10 years ago and PHP 4 is unsupported and has not received security updates for a very long time.

Comment: This answered all my questions, wanted to share it with you guys.
http://acko.net/blog/php-5-references-fun-clone-for-php4/

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
$cms_items = $items;
$cms_items->settings = $settings_cms;
```

does **not** create a seperate copy of `$settings_cms`.

To understand this you must know that an object variable doesn't hold the object itself, but only an object identifier that references the actual object in memory. So if you copy a variable that contains an object into a new variable, they will both contain the same object identifier, referencing to the same object.

So if you change something in `$settings_cms`, it will be changed in `$cms_items` as well, and vice versa - simply because they both contain a pointer to the same object.

Also see [Objects and references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php) in the PHP documentation.

If that's not what you want, and you want a seperate object instead, you need to [clone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) the object:

```
$cms_items->settings = clone $settings_cms;
```

Now you can change `$cms_items->settings` without changing `$settings_cms` and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, so this changed in between the different php versions ? Because on the old host it was working perfectly and the settings did not get override.

Comment: It would help if you could tell which versions of PHP both hosts use, but as far as I can see this is a feature of PHP 5. So if your old host was still using PHP 4, that could explain this issue.